# Entity Framework error when using Model First to generate code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

As can be seen in the above image, I've defined an Entity `Customer` with a primary key `Id`, a `FirstName` and a `LastName`. I saved the model file and tried to build the solution. I got the following build errors:

[image]

Im using Entity Framework 5 on Visual Studio 2012. My purpose is to design the model and then have the database code generated.
Any idea what might be wrong?

Here is some more info:

[image]

EDIT. Even more info:

[image]

Comment: I think you have created a customer model before this one and deleted it. You can clean it from `Model Browser`

Comment: Im pretty positive I didnt (I was getting this error in another project and I purposely created this new project to try to isolate the problem). See edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Model Browser and delete the duplicate properties there.

Comment: See the edited post. There doesnt seem to be anything repeated there.

Comment: try to set the 'Code Generation Strategy' to `None', and try again. Don't forget to clean the solution